# TOC Links not going to the correct place

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using kindle create. The TOC looks as I would expect it to though it does spill over on to a second screen which displays only the final two chapters. Sometimes when I click on a chapter number in the TOC it only takes me to the bottom of the TOC: that is to say the spill-over screen displaying the final two chapters.  I don't know what I can do about this.

Comment: could you please add some screenshots?